# Unit testing javascript with Gradle?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gradle, continuous-integration

I'm new to unit testing.  We have had some success with compiling and zipping js, compiling LESS and creating basic tasks to copy files.  Right now, though, I'm trying to do a sample unit test with a simple javascript function.  I have a QUnit test working in the browser, but I'm having trouble putting the pieces together.  What other tools or plugins do I need? What are my next steps?  What should my build.gradle look like?

Answer (score -1):

This is quite a broad question. What is your biggest issue?

I'm going to go ahead and assume it is actually getting a browser to start on you CI server and getting the results.

For that there are a number of options, easily found by searching for continuous intergration, javascript and unit test.

I found [Running JavaScript unit tests headlessly in a Continuous Integration build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070499/running-javascript-unit-tests-headlessly-in-a-continuous-integration-build) here on stackoverflow. This question has a good answer that you should be able to adapt for use with gradle.